# nw.js: <Webview> does not appear, how to get it to show?

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit

I am using nw.js to render the following index.html file which fails. Inspecting the element shows webview in the html code but it does not bother loading the desired url. How do I get it to display the target website in webview element with NW.js?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <style>
      * {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
      #webview {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        display: inline-flex !important;
      }      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <webview id="webview" src="https://reactjs.org" partition="trusted" />    

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a webview. There's been discussion around removing support for them. Use an iframe, if you really need to show a remote site.

That said, many people are using webviews right now without issue. Based on the documentation, I'm guessing you're missing the required entries in your manifest file: https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/webview%20Tag/

Comment: Does using iframe with `nwdisable` and `nwfaketop` same as `<webview>` in nw.js? The reason I wanted to use `<webview>` in nw.js is because it runs in a separate process according to NW.js https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/webview%20Tag/ . I'm surprised theres no discussion around this on the mailing list

Comment: Using those options will be very close to a `webview`, yes. Still technically the same process, but won't be allowed to access the parent or any of the built-in NW.js API.


For reference, here's the discussion where `webview` may be removed from Chromium: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/embedder-dev/c/1OvtnMhkteA/m/L8wNKWuDBAAJ

Comment: thank you. one last issue I am having, perhaps this can be solved by using webview? I am using iframe to load `https://asdf.com` and I get `net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` even though I enabled `nwfaketop` option and in package.json   `"chromium-args": "--enable-file-cookies --allow-running-insecure-content --ignore-certificate-errors"`. Strangely, when I load from a normal chrome browser i can load `https://asdf.com` in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

we need to know if you also enabled it in your package.json

You should have some code like that in the JSON

```json
"webview": {
  "partitions": [
     {
       "name": "trusted",
       "accessible_resources": [
          "<all_urls>"
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```